# Passing arguments to a function used by Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to do multiprocessing on some files. The files belong to two different categories namely `A` and `B`. The idea is to iterate over all the files where the filenames are contained in two lists `category_A` and `category_B`. Here is a simple class that I have written for doing multiprocessing:

```
class ImageProc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def __call__(self, sample, category="A"):
        subject = str(sample)
        sample = loadmat(sample)
        age  = int(sample["Age"][0][0])
        nb_images = sample['images'].shape[2]
        del sample
        for i in range(nb_images):
            self.data.append((subject, category, age, i))
        gc.collect()

# This works fine for category A
proc = ImageProc()
pool = Pool()
_ = pool.map(proc, category_A)
```

But now I want to use the same instance and call the same function for `category_B` for which I have to explicitly pass the argument `category="B"` in the `__call__` method. Can anyone please help me how to achieve that?

EDIT: Given the useful comments, I also want to elaborate that this list, represented here by `self.data`, is common for both `category_A` and `category_B`. If I make it global, then it won't be possible use the pool instances on the same list to write data.

Comment: Depending on your use case, `pool.starmap(...)` may be an option for you, to achieve what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)

Comment: @JohanL can you give an example?

Comment: @stovfl this one is similar but the implementation is totally different. Using same instance makes it a special case here I guess

Comment: You _cannot_ get the exact same instance when using `multiprocessing`. Each process will have its own instance, and that is irrespective of whether you use only category A or both A and B.

Comment: @JohanL then how should I proceed?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. I don't even know what you are trying to achieve or why you want to use the same instance in different processes.